# removing element from a composite / array (composite pattern)

Tags: php

I'm studying patterns and playing around with an example at the moment, however I can't seem to get removeUnit method to work as expected. Here's the code:

```
 <?php
abstract class Unit
{
    abstract function strength();
    public function getComposite()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * composite / group class
 */
abstract class Composite extends Unit
{
    private $_units = array();

    // check if class is a composite or not
    public function getComposite()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getUnits()
    {
        return $this->_units;
    }

    // add a unit to the group
    public function addUnit(Unit $unit)
    {
        if( in_array($unit, $this->_units, true) ) {
            Throw new exception("Sorry, the following unit is already in the army");
        } else {
            array_push($this->_units, $unit);
        }
    }

    //remove a unit from the group
    public function removeUnit(Unit $unit)
    {
        if( ! in_array($unit, $this->_units, true) ) {
            Throw new Exception("Hm, it looks like this unit is not a part of this army.");
        } else {
            $key = array_search($unit, $this->_units);
            array_splice($this->_units, $key);
        }
    }
}

class Army extends Composite
{
    public function strength()
    {
        $units = $this->getUnits();
        $armyStrength = 0;
        foreach( $units as $unit ) {
            $armyStrength += $unit->strength();
        }
        return $armyStrength;
    }
}

class Riffle extends Unit
{
    public function strength()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class Rocket extends Unit
{
    public function strength()
    {
        return 15;
    }
}

$riffle1 = new Riffle();
$riffle2 = new Riffle();
$riffle3 = new Riffle();

$rocket1 = new Rocket();
$rocket2 = new Rocket();
$rocket3 = new Rocket();

$squad = new Army();

$squad->addUnit($riffle1);
$squad->addUnit($riffle2);
$squad->addUnit($rocket1);
$squad->removeUnit($riffle2);
echo $squad->strength();
```

The problem is here:

```
//remove a unit from the group
public function removeUnit(Unit $unit)
{
    if( ! in_array($unit, $this->_units, true) ) {
        Throw new Exception("Hm, it looks like this unit is not a part of this army.");
    } else {
        $key = array_search($unit, $this->_units);
        array_splice($this->_units, $key);
    }
}
```

if I remove recket1 the everything works fine, but if I try to remove riffle1 or 2 then my strength returns 0. What's the problem here? and is there a better way to remove an element from an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array_splice` call is wrong, because omitting the `$length` argument removes everything from that point up to the end of the array. It should be:

```
array_splice($this->_units, $key, 1);
```

That said, I 'm not sure why you bother to preserve numeric indexes in the first place -- using `unset($this->_units[$key])` would also do the trick without any obvious side effects.

Finally, there's no point in doing `in_array` and `array_search` independently. You could rewrite the code like this:

```
$key = array_search($unit, $this->_units);
if ($key === false) {
    // exception
}

array_splice($this->_units, $key, 1);
```

Comment: Makes sense, this works perfectly, thank you. I didn't even think of just using unset()

Comment: @haosmark: You are also using `array_push` instead of `$arr[] = $newItem` -- personally I have never used `array_push`. The only use I can think for it is treating it as a callback, which you cannot do with the special array syntax.